# send_file works but does not let user specify target filename/folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I letting users download files

```
def download
  options = { :filename => @file_name, :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment' }
  send_file(@path, options)
end
```

This works and user sees an Open or Save File dialog. However user is never given a chance to specify neither file name nor a target folder for the downloaded file. Is there a way I can allow this additional flexibility using rails standard send_file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those settings you have to set up on your browser.